# Entity validating configuration (NOT model validation!)

Tags: entity-framework, validation

We're writing an Entity layer for our database, and with 160-some-odd tables there's surely room for error.  We're using the fluent configuration with the `EntityTypeConfiguration<T>` objects.  Is there a utility we can run afterwards to ensure that our FK's and PK's and tables are all properly linked up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up creating a T4 template to generate a unit test for this.